# axios get request Error: Request failed with status code 504

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

here is my code that makes an Http Get request to an API end point from one of the services running on Amazon Fargate service. The API is powered by Amazon API gateway and Lambda. Also this is a private api used with in the VPC and I also have setup the apigateway VPC end point to facilitate the same. I have received this error only once. All the subsequent calls made to the API were successful.

My suspicion is that the lambda was not warm and that resulted a timeout. I am going to try setting a timeout for the axios code. any suggestions welcome

```
async getItems(): Promise < any > {
  try {

    let url = `https://vpce-[id].execute-api.ap-southeast-2.vpce.amazonaws.com/prod/items`


    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'x-apigw-api-id': `[api-id]`
      }
    });

    return response.data;

  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out my lambda is timing out after the 30 seconds configured time. I could increase the lambda timeout, but the configurable timeout for API gateway is 30 seconds.

It has only happened once and i believe that it's because lambda cold start. As a workaround, I am taking the `retry` approach. The API request will be retried 3 times.